# Header data aligned to natural length?

Tags: networking, header

I was looking through RFC 3550 and ran across this line and was not sure what it meant:

> All header data is aligned to its natural length, i.e., 16-bit fields are aligned on even offsets, 32-bit
>   fields are aligned at offsets divisible by four, etc. Octets designated as padding have the value zero.

I tried looking around to figure out using keyword searches but haven't had any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields that are 16 bit long (2 bytes) will start at offsets divisible by 2 bytes (byte 0, 2, 4, etc). Fields that are 32 bits will start at byte 0, 4, 8, etc.
The offset is relative to the start of the header (and of the packet).
For example, if you have a header with a 16 bit (2 byte) field A and a 32 bit (4 byte) field B it will have to be arranged as follows:

```
A             : 2 bytes
padding(zero) : 2 bytes
B             : 4 bytes
```

Here A starts at offset 0 and B starts at offset 4.

Comment: Thanks for helping clear that up! If I could ask you one more question: why is this done instead of just appending them one after the other?

Comment: @Shaun Not all machines have (or have always had) the ability to access fields that are not "properly" aligned.  And TCP/IP stacks derive much of their performance from avoiding moving buffer fields around in memory.